# FileStream returns Length = 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream

I'm trying to read a local file and upload it on ftp server. when i read a image file, everything is ok, but when i read a doc or docx file, FileStream returns length = 0. Here is my code:
i checked with some other files, it appears that it only works fine with images and it returns 0 for any other file

```
if (!ftpClient.FileExists(fileName))
{
    try
    {
        ftpClient.ValidateCertificate += (control, e) => { e.Accept = true; };

        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 64 * 1024; // 64KB buffer
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        using (Stream readStream = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (Stream writeStream = ftpClient.OpenWrite(fileName))
        {
            while (readStream.Position < readStream.Length)
            {
                buffer.Initialize();
                int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            readStream.Flush();
            readStream.Close();
            writeStream.Flush();
            writeStream.Close();
            DeleteTempFile(tempFilePath);
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I couldn't find whats wrong with it. could you please help me?

Comment: Does it only happen to doc/docx files? Is the access different from the image files?

Comment: Are you saying that `readStream.Length` is zero? Have you tested that with a debugger, or assuming it based on getting a zero-sized file on the ftp server? If the latter, I'd suggest you log exceptions as something is likely going wrong and how are simply returning false when it does.

Comment: i checked with some other files, it appears that it only works fine with images and it returns 0 for any other file

Comment: So in a completely clean project `File.OpenRead(path).Length` is zero on a `.doc` file that is definitely larger than zero? Are you sure? Are you sure that the `tempFile` is larger than 0 bytes? Did you write `tempFile` correctly in the first place? Did you close and flush the `FileStream` that created `tempFile`?

Comment: yes, the file is definitely larger than zero. and yes i close and flush after saving tempFile

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't answer your specific question, you don't actually need to know the length of your stream. Just keep reading until you hit a zero length read. [A zero byte read is guaranteed to indicate the the end of any stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#returns).

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Int32
>
> The total number of bytes read into the buffer. This can be less than the number of bytes requested if that many bytes are not currently available, or zero (0) if the end of the stream has been reached.

```
while (true)
{
    int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
    if(bytesRead==0)
    {
        break;
    }
    writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

alternatively:

```
readStream.CopyTo(writeStream);
```

is probably the most concise method of stating your goal...

Comment: i tried readStream.CopyTo(writeStream); but it still creates an empty file

Answer (score 0):

it was just a silly mistake, i have two fileupload and i've saved the other fileupload, so it creates a zero length file. as it appears the code works fine.
thanks everyone.